# How to use raw FTP STOR command

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

I am trying to upload a file to an FTP server using raw commands. Yes, I know there are programs and packages to do this, but mine is an embedded application without such luxuries. My problem is that after successfully issuing all the appropriate commands, I find that the file does not exist on the server.

Here's what I did:

1. I establish a command socket connection to my FTP server on port 21 (Sock1) and receive greeting (code 220)
2. I send "USER *myusername*" and receive success code 331
3. I send "PASS *mypassword*" and receive success code 230
4. I send "TYPE I" and receive success code 200
5. I send "PASV" and receive success code 227 along with 6 numbers.
6. I decode these numbers into an IP address and port. They look reasonable.
7. I successfully open a TCP data socket connection to the address and port above (Sock2).
8. I send "STOR *myfilename*" and receive success code 150.
9. I successfuly send the contents of *myfilename* to Sock2.
10. I close Sock2, then Sock1.

Everything seems to have gone Ok, but no file on server. Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

I know the server's Ok because I can upload the file using various FTP client programs (using PUT command).

Comment: This looks mainly ok except that you should wait for the server to acknowledge the successful transport, i.e. in step#10 close sock2, wait for the 226 from server and only then close sock1. And maybe also add a quit command including waiting for the response before closing sock1. Apart from that it might be that your actual implementation differs from what you describe here.

Comment: You were right Steffen, closing sock2 first and waiting for 226 fixed it. If you submit this as an "answer", I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 9. I successfuly send the contents of myfilename to Sock2.
> 10. I close Sock2, then Sock1.

When the transfer is done the data connection (sock2) need to be closed to signal the end of data to the server. The server will then reply with a 226 response to the client. This response should be read before closing the control channel (sock1). If sock1 and sock2 are closed at almost the same time like done here it might happen that the server notes the close of the control channel (sock1) before the close of the data channel (sock2) and will thus treat the data transport as aborted.